# how to upload internal storage image to server in react native. image not uploading to server. in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, file-upload, server, digital-signature

I am new to react native. I am trying to upload my digital signature image which is stored in internal storage.
path is like this = '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/1616657741752.png'.
but image not uploading then think that the problem is with this path - '/storage/emulated/0'.
because there no folder called DCIM in '/storage/emulated/0' this path.
so I remove this - '/storage/emulated/0' by using below code

```
this.setState({base64: paths.split('/storage/emulated/0').pop()})
```

But still same problem my image not uploading to server. over all my image is visible in my phone internal storage in DCIM folder. I do not know what to do now.
here is my code

```
 base64:null,

_onSaveEvent = (result) => {
    this.checkAndroidPermission(result)
    }
    
    checkAndroidPermission = async (result) => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    save(result);
    } else {
    try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    // Once user grant the permission start downloading
    
    this.save(result);
    } else {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    ToastAndroid.show('Storage Permission denied.', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    } else {
    AlertIOS.alert('Storage Permission denied.');
    }
    }
    } catch (err) {
    // To handle permission related exception
    console.warn('tryerr', err);
    }
    }
    };
    
    save = async (result) => {
    const paths = `${
    RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DCIMDir
    }/${new Date().getTime()}.png`; // where u need to put that
    try {
    RNFetchBlob.fs
    .writeFile(paths, result.encoded, 'base64')//data.base64 is your photo with convert base64
    .then((value) => {
    RNFetchBlob.fs
    .scanFile([{path: paths}]) //after save to notify gallry for that
    .then(() => {
      this.setState({base64: paths.split('/storage/emulated/0').pop()})
    console.log('scan file success');
    console.log("this is fuckiiing file"+ this.state.base64)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
    console.log('scan file error');
    });
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e.message));
    } catch (error) {
    console.log('fileerror', error.message);
    }
    
    }


 
         formData.append('digital_signature',this.state.base64);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(formData))
    fetch('https://abc.tech/Android_API_CI/upload_multipart_data',
      {
        method: 'post',
          body : formData, 
          
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',
        },



 <SignatureCapture
                              style={styles.signature}
                              ref="sign"
                              onSaveEvent={this._onSaveEvent}
                              onDragEvent={this._onDragEvent}
                              saveImageFileInExtStorage={true}
                              showNativeButtons={false}
                              showTitleLabel={false}
                              viewMode={'portrait'}
                            />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is your Ans and also put into the function may this helps**

```
const file = {
      uri:
        Platform.OS == 'android'
          ? '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/1616657741752.png' //path to your file 
          : 'file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/1616657741752.png',
      name: 'sign.png', // which go on server on your file name
      type: 'image/png', // e.g. 'image/jpg'
    };
    

formData.append('digital_signature',file);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(formData))
    fetch('https://abc.tech/Android_API_CI/upload_multipart_data',
      {
        method: 'post',
          body : formData, 
          
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',
        },
```

Comment: I think I have to change image path is it possbile. because my other image which is I capture from camera using Image picker. are uploading to server and there path is like this = ["upload_pancard",{"uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.nasdigitalapp/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_d27ae8b2-8ed9-4f45-b39c-278878ee1fb8.jpg","name":"pancardImage.jpg","type":"image/*"}]

Comment: thanks bro very very very much thanks. i just replace this = '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/1616657741752.png' with our paths. and boom it work